# JavaFX print to GUI TextArea from another class outside Controller

Tags: java, javafx

How can I print to a GUI `TextArea` from outside the `Controller` class?

I have the `method` from another class called `Alarm`:

```
public boolean maggotAttack(int nothealthy) {
    int maggot = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    if (maggot == 1) {

        System.out.println("A maggot is destroying the plant, heal the plant!");
        return true;

    } else if (maggot == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want the `print` to get printet to the GUI instead of the console. I do not want to make an instance of my `Controller` and then use the `TextArea` in the `method` above, because that is against good software layers as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved by another one in another question i made with more detail. The problem was, that I just needed to set the class which I want to access my controller, as a controller. So the answer is, refer your class as a controller, better shown here:
[JavaFXML reference to Controller from all classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958457/javafxml-reference-to-controller-from-all-classes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should study the [MVC pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) in detail. If you use this practice, as I suggest you should, then you would have a controller class that holds a reference to a view of some kind. You can then pass that view into your code somehow (e.g. a setter, as a parameter, etc) then use that view to display what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextAreaOutputStream out = new JTextAreaOutputStream (textArea);
System.setOut (new PrintStream (out));
```

Use your TextArea to create an JTextAreaOutputStream and redirect the printstream. Then you can always use System.out.println();

Comment: Isn't that Swing? I am using JavaFX, does it matter?